# Series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{\Gamma(b+nc)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

$a,b,c$ be positive real numbers, and $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function, find

> $$
>  \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{a^n}{\Gamma(b+nc)}
> $$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. People may be more willing to help if you could share what you thought, any ideas that you tried etc

Comment: I can provide a solution for the case when $c=1$.

Comment: Do you know what the gamma function is and how power series converge?

Comment: Here is a hint, I assume $b, c \in \mathbb{N}$. Write the gamma function in terms of $\gamma(d+1) = d!$ and then look at the normal exponentiel series: $exp(z) = \sum_{k\ge0}\frac{z^k}{k!}$

Comment: @LonesSmith just in case, I do not know if this could help or not, but Wolfram Alpha converts this to a MittagLeffler case, MittagLefflerE(c, b, a), but it is not able to compute the value... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Ba%5En%2FGamma%5Bb+%2B+n+c%5D,+%7Bn,+0,+Infinity%7D%5D

Comment: @LonesSmith another reference from my former comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MittagLefflerE

Comment: What do you mean by *find*? Find a simple closed form, find an arbitrarily accurate approximation, find an integral representation... ?

Comment: Find a simple closed form if possible, howsoever simple that may be. Approximations might be helpful, as I just do not understand how it responds to the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Providing solution in the $c=1$ case. Let me know in the comments if $a,b,c$  are natural numbers, in that case it can be solved without any such assumption, but even there the underlying idea won't change. 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{a^n}{\Gamma(b+n)}
$$
Now as $$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$$ 
This gives us on repeated application
$$\Gamma(b+n)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1
}{(b+k)}   \Gamma(b)$$
Therefore our sum becomes
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(b)} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{a^n}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1
}{(b+k)}}}$$

Can you take it from here; does the sum  look familiar now?

Comment: I only know that a,b,c are positive real numbers.

Comment: The above solution will also work if $c$ was an integer and a,b were just reals. Unfortunately, I can't think of anything if c is also real and I doubt if there is.